# In MongoDb is collection creation during an insert/update an atomic operation?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to create a race condition on the first insert of a collection to MongoDB from 2 different clients?

If a collection doesn't yet exist and two different applications try to write to it is it possible that there will be some sort of race condition where both try to create the collection or is the Collection creation during a write an atomic operation that couldn't allow such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to a [MongoDB meetup last night](http://www.phxmug.org/events/55439142/) and was able to ask this directly to a [10gen](http://www.10gen.com/) Enginner.
His answer indicated that the create collection/write to collection is one operation and could not cause a race condition that would fail the 2nd write.